# Overriding database details in yaml for Doctrine from PHP in Symfony

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony, password-protection

I am new to Symfony and am at the stage where I have done some templates and have connected to the database (Oracle at work, mysql at home).

However, I just have the details in the yaml file at the moment, and that is not very secure. In our PHP apps (that will move to Symfony) PHP deals with secure passwords and we may end up using something like Password Manager Pro or certificates.

How can I override whats in the yaml file and deal with the password, connection string etc from within PHP?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html#environment-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference (from http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html#environment-variables, thanks malcolm), do the following:

1) Add a parameters.php into app/config/ with the following code:

```
<?php // app/config/parameters.php
$container->setParameter('database_name', 'dbname');
$container->setParameter('database_user', 'username');
$container->setParameter('database_password', 'password');
```

You can add whatever parameters you want from your parameters.yml file (or any others in your config).

2) Import this file by adding the following to the imports: section of config.yml:

```
- { resource: parameters.php }
```

This will now make this section look something like:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: parameters.php }
```

and is normally at the start of the config.yml.

Now anything in parameters.php fill overwrite anything in the parameters.yml file.